# ember member actions normalizing response

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember member API actions and was wondering how can response be normalized in such cases.

I have a model "users" with member action "postAddress". It is a post request which returns me a response. Now the problem I am facing is data is not normalized as returned data does not map to any store model. I know when we do a findAll and give a model, then ember automatically normalizes the data returned from API call. But in case of member actions, can anyone suggest how can data be normalized? (snake case to camel case).

Comment: is member actions an addon you're using?

Comment: https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions

Comment: can you provide your configuration / sample code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I will try to make a twiddle or something to show the code but in general all I am trying is to invoke a member api action which is nothing but a convenient way to make REST calls and then response returned is in snake case format and I want to make it camel case (which store is not doing as of now)

Comment: do you have something like this? https://gitlab.com/precognition-llc/aeonvera-ui/blob/master/app/adapters/application.js#L13

Comment: doh, sorry -- this would be a serializer thing.

do you have something like this? https://gitlab.com/precognition-llc/aeonvera-ui/blob/master/app/serializers/application.js#L12

Comment: yes i have this. but i guess this is when UI sends data to backend and not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

[`ember-api-actions`](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions) addon does not provide any serializer integration. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions/issues/194) about it. As discussed there you could manually push the response to store using [`pushPayload`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Store/methods/pushPayload?anchor=pushPayload) method of `store` service provided by Ember Data.

If you don't want to push the data into the store but just use a Serializer to normalize the response, you could do so by combining [`serializerFor()` method of DS.Store](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Store/methods/serializerFor?anchor=serializerFor) and [`normalizeResponse()` method of DS.Serializer](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Serializer/methods/normalizeResponse?anchor=normalizeResponse).

Comment: but pushPayload does not return anything. So how can I get back the normalized data?

Comment: @BhavyaBansal: Extended my answer so that it also covers deserializing manually if you are not interested in pushing the response into the store at all.